# Lifecycle exception in tomcat

Tags: struts2, tomcat7

I'm getting `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException` when running shopizer project in eclipse. Shopizer use struts2. Also I'm using tomcat7 to run it. The bad thing is some times it comes and sometimes it don't. When It comes restarting the server is not helping and I have to restart the whole system to get things working again.

Comment: can you provide more details and with complete exception log? I believe you are using Shopizer version 1.1.5 or less? in case you can also log this issue at http://www.shopizer.com/forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open task manager.
kill the process 'javaw.exe' 
then restart the server after cleaning tomcat directory and project
it should work..